# Compare an Object property inside a vector to a String

Tags: c++, object, vector, find

What I am trying to do is match an Objects data member inside a vector to a specific string "HP Pot" and return true if there is a match.
The vector in question is a Backpack that can take MP Potions and HP Potions.
Potions is a class.

```
vector<Potions> backpack;

Potions* hpPotion = new Potions("HP Pot", 5, 5);
Potions* mpPotion = new Potions("MP Pot", 5, 5);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    backpack.push_back(*hpPotion);
    backpack.push_back(*mpPotion);
}
```

I want a Player (another class) to be able to use potions if available while running the combat method of Player. 
The combat definition looks as follows.

```
bool Player::attack(Monster& monster, vector<Potions> &backpack, Potions* hpPotion, Potions* mpPotion)
```

Inside this definition I implement the find function.

```
    string myString = "HP Pot";
        if (backpack.empty())
        {
            cout << "No potions found!" << endl;
        }
        else if (find(backpack.begin(), backpack.end(), [myString](const Potions& hpPotion)
        {return hpPotion.getName() == myString; }) = backpack.end())
        {
            cout << "Hp potion found!" << endl;
        }
```

The getName() Method is defined as follows.

```
string Potions::getName()
{
    return mName;   //Where mName is a private Data Member of Potions
}
```

The problem I get is that *hpPotion->getName()* should be of Pointer type. But when I change it to *hpPotion.getName()* it tells me that the Object is using an Oprator that is not compatible with the *"Potions::getName()"* Method

If you guys have another way of finding out if a Specific Data Member "HP Pot" of Object Potions is equals to "HP Pot" please let me know.

Comment: What does `getName` return and what is the type of `myString` ?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message with `hpPotion.getName()`?

Comment: How about not trying to assign `backpack.end()` to the result of `std::find`? It should be `!=` anyway.

Comment: Or use `std::any_of` if you just want to check the existence and don't care about the position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to be using `find` here. The last argument of `find` should have the same type as what is returned by the iterator. Thus, in your case, the last argument should be potion. You are inputting a lambda expression that outputs a boolean. If you want to do it like this you should use `find_if`. A simpler solution however would be to just create a function that checks if a potion is in the backpack like this.

```
bool hasPotion(vector<Potions> & backPack, Potions & potion)
{
   for(auto iter = backPack.begin(); iter!= backPack.end(); ++iter)
   {
       if (iter->getName() == potion.getName())
           return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

As mentioned by others there are several issues with your code. I will just give a few comments on some of this as well.

You are allocating and creating pointers to potions. The `vector::push_back` function creates a copy of object that is passed into it. After you have put the potions in the backpack you have two dangling pointers that needs to be cleaned up. Instead you might as well create the potions normally and they will be cleaned up automatically. thus you would have

```
vector<Potions> backpack;

Potions hpPotion = Potions("HP Pot", 5, 5);
Potions mpPotion = Potions("MP Pot", 5, 5);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    backpack.push_back(hpPotion);
    backpack.push_back(mpPotion);
}
```

Additionally, identifying the type of object using a string is not really a good idea as it very error prone. A better solution would be to have an Enum inside to potion class to identify the type of potion. Alternatively you could create classes that derive from the `Potions` class for each type of potion.

Lastly, while I don't really know much about your design, I think passing in hp potions and mana potions into `attack` separately seems strange. You are specifically creating a way to identify the type potion. You could simply accept a list of potions, or even just potion types.

Comment: I used your solution and it worked wonderfully. I hope that with a lot of work I will get to think as clearly as you do when confronted with a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Overlooking all the other issues in the code you have posted (things like `=` instead of `!=`, no idea of the return type of `getName()` and `myString`,  etc.), I think the operator not compatible error is due to `==` operator not compatible with the types of `getName()` and `myString`. More details about the types would certainly help.